# Different backgrounds for pages generated from for loop in one css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got stuck with different background images I need for each page the ID of which is generated from the following for loop statement:

```
`$`function nextButton() {
    if(curNum<numScreens) {
      curNum = parseInt(curNum)+1;
      document.location.href = '#'+curNum;
      $( init );
   }
}
```

so I get /#1, /#2 and /#3 pages.

I tried to assign independent id/class for each page in html document like that:

```
<body id="1">
<body id="2">
<body id="3">
```

and then in the css:

```
body.1 { background-image: url("bg.gif"); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 53% 10%;
z-index: 1;
}
body.2 { background-image: url("bg1.gif"); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 53% 10%;
z-index: 1;}

body.3 { background-image: url("bg2.gif"); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 53% 10%;
z-index:1 }
```

but it does not work.
Can you help me, please ?

Comment: This may be a typo, but in the html the body has an `id`, and in the css you are accessing it by `class` (`.` selector)

Comment: Also, classes and ids can't lead with a number. Try leading with '#body-1' or something.

Comment: I confirm that @Torr3nt is correct, cannot lead classes or IDs with a number.

Answer (score 0):

just change each of the body.1, body.2, and body.3 to:

```
body #body_1 {...}
body #body_2 {...}
body #body_3 {...}
```